# ember converting ajax query string

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, ember-data, ember-model

I'm using ember-model and doing this request `App.Video.find({'sort':'createdAt+asc'});` in order to get sorted video list. So it must make this request

`http://localhost:1337/api/v1/videos?sort=createdAt+asc`

But instead it does this

```
http://localhost:1337/api/v1/videos?sort=createdAt%2Basc
```

and replace `+` with `%2B`. Do you have any ideas how to avoid ember doing this? Thank you!

Comment: Don't do that, you'll risk generating an invalid URL. Just unescape the parameters on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember runs `encodeURIComponent` on the string `'createdAt+asc'`.

Try doing `App.Video.find({'sort':'createdAt asc'});` (note the space instead of the +) and seeing if that works for you.